# como muestro un array de objetos en un input y que no se muestren datos de otros arreglos?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify

tengo datos enviados de una api y los quiero mostrar en inputs ,el problema es que tengo un array de teléfonos y emails que solo se muestra uno solo , o si no tiene email uno de los datos ,queda vacío o se muestra un email de un dato viejo, mi pregunta seria: como puedo mostrar ese array de objetos en el input? y como mostrar solo los emails y teléfonos de ese dato y no de un dato mostrado anteriormente?

JavaScript:

```
    for(telefono of response.data.sucEmpresa.sucTelefonos) {
       // recorrer telefono para mostrarlos todos
       this.telefonoArrayTab = telefono.telefono.nroTlefono
       console.log("telefono:"+' '+this.telefonoArrayTab)
    }

    for(email of response.data.sucEmpresa.sucEmails) {
      // recorrer emails para mostrarlos todos
      this.emailArrayTab = email.email.email
      console.log("email:"+' '+this.emailArrayTab)
      if(this.emailArrayTab===this.emailArrayTab) {
           console.log(this.emailArrayTab)
      } else {
          console.log("email vacio")
      }
    }
    
    response.data.sucEmpresa.sucTelefonos[0].telefono.nroTlefono
    this.telefonoTab = this.telefonoArrayTab
      
       
    this.emailTab = this.emailArrayTab
```

HTML:

```
 

<p>
   <v-subheader cols="1" id="achicar" class="text-left">Telefono</v-subheader>
</p>
<v-col cols="2" class="text-left">
   <v-text-field 
      hide-details="auto"
      placeholder="TELEFONO"
      id=telefonoTab
      type="text" 
      v-model="telefonoTab"              
      readonly>
   </v-text-field>
</v-col>
<p>
   <v-subheader cols="1" id="achicar" class="text-left">Email</v-subheader>
</p>
<v-col cols="2" class="text-left">
   <v-text-field 
      hide-details="auto"
      placeholder="EMAIL"
      id=emailTab
      type="text" 
      v-model="emailTab"              
      readonly>
   </v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen muestra los datos de api que son teléfono y email los que me generan problemas

Comment: segun lo que entiendo, es que quieres juntar ambos valores?, podrias poner algun ejemplo de la respuesta de tu api?

aunque sean datos irreales, pero que tengan la misma estructura

Comment: en la imagen se ven los valores, queda algo asi por ejemplo : telefono: 123 ,abajo telefono:456, esos serian dos telefonos de los valores de la api y tambien me devuelve :  email:qwe@gmail.com ,email:rty@gmail.com que serian dos emails

Comment: va por lo que veo trae 2 valores telefono: xxx-xxx-xx-xx, lo que se me ocurre es concatenar esos valores y separarlos por ','

Comment: los concatene poniendo por ejemplo this.telefono + ('-')+this.telefono pero al hacer una consulta distinta me muestra los números de otros usuarios distintos

Answer (score 0):

Me atrevo a poner algo..

lo que hacemos es concatenar los campos con la funcion reduce

'use strict'

```js
let arr = [{ telefono: '656-123-11-22', email: 'test@test.mx' }, { telefono: '656-123-33-44', email: 'text2@test.com' }]
let rr = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    return { ...el, telefono: el.telefono + ',' + el.telefono, email: el.email + ',' + el.email };
}, []);

console.log(rr)
```

)

de esta manera tendrias acceso a los valores en uno mismo, supongo que es ello

Comment: si algo así quiero mostrar ,pero cono son valores de una api a veces tiene 0 teléfonos , a veces 1 ,2, o hasta 4 , y no se si así se pueda hacer dinámico, o si?

Comment: si, intentalo con ese codigo, asi te concatena todo, tenga o no datos